# PostgreSQL query returns undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, postgresql

I'm trying to connect my postgreSQL database to a node.js application but it keeps returning undefined whenever I try to log some of the data to the console using "node file_name".

I have a table called "users" and I want to log it's columns as arrays to the console to make sure that my database is connected to the app currectly

I tried almost all the solutions on Stack overflow but none of them worked for me

```
const { Client } = require('pg')

const client = new Client({
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 5432,
    database: 'postgres',
    user: 'postgres',
    password: '******'
})

client.connect()

client.query('SELECT * FROM users', (res, err)=> {
    if (!err) {
        console.log(res.rows)
    } else {
        console.log(err.message)
    }
    client.end()
})
```

Comment: I am not familiar with the package, but having a quick look, all the query examples seem to use (err, res) instead of (res, err). Is it possible these the wrong way around?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Just a suggestion:** Rather than dumping your `users` table to verify the connection run the following:

```
select version()
     , current_database()
     , current_schemas ( false );
```

This will tell you exactly what you have connected to and the available path (schema list) in order searched and do so in 1 row returned. Your current verification query dumps the `users` table; if you 1000s of users you get 1000s of rows on the console.